# Ionic Angular Controller Execute Twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have made an ionic app but the controller execute twice.

My Stateprovider

```
config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

    .state('index', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '/templates/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })

    .state('step1', {
        url: '/step1/',
        templateUrl: '/templates/step1.html',
        controller: 'Step1Ctrl'
    })
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

My Controllers:

```
    .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $http, $rootScope, $timeout ) {}
    .controller('Step1Ctrl', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $http, $rootScope, $timeout ) {
//This Code execute twice
$scope.$on('$ionicParentView.beforeEnter', function () {
promise1 = $timeout(function () { $state.go('index'); }, 30000);
})
};
```

My index:

```
<body ng-app="starter">
      <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
```

I have search for days now and nothing works.
Can you help me?

I edit my code and inside the controller I put the timeout that execute twice

Comment: how you can say it execute twice?

Comment: I have a timeout. In console log the timeout fires twice

Comment: are you checking in browser or real device?

Comment: And browser and real device

Comment: for browser are you using `ionic serve --lab` or only `ionic serve`

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2015 with apache cordova

Comment: it is hard to identify from above code. because there is nothing wrong in above code.

Comment: Are you sure this code is working , I think There is syntax error in your controller ,you are not closing it right